# RemoveHandler not working

Tags: vb.net, handler

I want to change the text of a textbox with the TextChange event but the TextChanged evernt keeps triggering.

I try RemoveHandler but it is not working for me. It, however, works when I use it outside of the _TextChanged Sub.

```
Private Sub txtLegalNameLast_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtLegalNameLast.TextChanged
    RemoveHandler txtLegalNameLast.TextChanged, AddressOf txtLegalNameLast_TextChanged
    txtLegalNameLast.Text = "Mr. " + txtLegalNameLast.Text 
    AddHandler txtLegalNameLast.TextChanged, AddressOf txtLegalNameLast_TextChanged    

End Sub
```

EDIT: The above works for me. I should have tested it. But this very similar code does not. I am making changes to the textbox in Functions outside the Sub. This isn't working for me.

```
Private Sub txtLegalNameLast_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtLegalNameLast.TextChanged

        RemoveHandler txtLegalNameLast.TextChanged, AddressOf txtLegalNameLast_TextChanged

        txtLegalNameLast.Text = gsCapitalizeTextbox(txtLegalNameLast.Text) 'StrConv(txtLegalNameLast.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
        txtLegalNameLast.Text = gsValidateName(txtLegalNameLast.Text)

        AddHandler txtLegalNameLast.TextChanged, AddressOf txtLegalNameLast_TextChanged

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me with the exact same code in VB.NET, .NET 4.0, VS2010. But apart from that, you know this event will be triggered every time a letter is typed by the user?

Comment: RemoveHandler works fine.  The code you wrote does not, it keeps putting "Mr. " in front of the string every time you press a key.  That's your bug, not a framework bug.

Comment: Crazy it works for you but not for me. I am on VB .NET 3.5.

Ignore the "Mr." part since it isn't the defect I am talking about, I just put it in there for the example to make the text change so the event triggers again.

Comment: I have edited my main post. Would you know why this is not working for me then? (Why did my code all just go to one single line that I can't seem to fix!)

Comment: Try the `Validated` event instead of `TextChanged`

Comment: My guess would be that you have another AddHandler somewhere, in which case the RemoveHandler isn't removing "all" of the event triggers.